# How can i get the correct changes in datagridview combobox column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a

```
datagridview
```

in which i have a

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
```

as one of the column.

This column's

```
ColumnType = DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.
```

In this combo box i have some items like admin,user,animal,human and birds. First item that is displayed when grid view loads is **admin** (notice the lowercase letter.).

Everything is working fine but the problem arises - whenever user is changing the name admin to **Admin/ADMIN/aDMin** etc. and then clicking anywhere else in the gridview then this column again showing the admin in the column but when the same scenario is done but this time user presses the enter or tab button , its value changed.

I am not understanding why this happened?

What is the difference between **click** and **Enter/Tab** for this combo box?

one more thing is that if user is typing any other word except "admin" , its value changed successfully even on click.

I think the problem arises when i am typing the uppercase letter or the mixture of upper and lower case letters.

Same thing happened with the other items of the combo box such as animal/birds etc.

Comment: With Enter or Tab, you remain on the same row. When clicking on an other row, the DataGridView validates the row. If I remember well (I am sure in case of bounded DataGridViewComboBoxColumn), the combobox is in DropDownList mode preventing user to set a value not belonging to the list.

Comment: What if there is only one row and user is clicking on the blank space of the gridview ; The problem is same in that condition also. @Graffito

Comment: Clicking on the blank row also triggers the row validation.

Comment: SO is there any solution for it? @Graffito

Comment: Display style = ComboBox

Comment: What is your objective 1) do you want that any input shall belong to items list 2) a possibility to enter values not belonging to list.

Comment: first one :) _the choice  2) is much more complicated_ I think that you may solve the problem by implementing the CellValidating event.

Comment: already do with that but no result as formatted value is not giving correct value. @Graffito